# iOS decline iphone 5 resize

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have been recently building an application, and although I love how the iPhone 5 has a bunch more space, I hate their autoresize in storyboard (regardless of unchecking autoresize). Is there a way to turn off autoresize somewhere for the entire project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1: Head into storyboard**

**2: Click any view controller you might have**

**3: Click on file inspector**

**4: Turn off autolayout there**

[image: Storyboard]

Then you can use the good old struts and springs again, but it can cause you a bit of trouble when making layouts for the different formats.

**Explanation on what Autolayout is and why you should probably use it: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2**

Comment: Yeah. It does give me some trouble go back and forth between the two. I'd like to shut it off now. But thanks! Is that possible?

Comment: Ya... just tick off the mark saying "Use Autolayout", then it doesn't use autolayout anymore. I'd suggest learning autolayout a bit more though. You are most likely heading for trouble if you don't use it. That's my experience at least.

Comment: Added a link above to a quick little tutorial about auto layout

Comment: Thanks for the link. Raywenderlich is a good site. Didn't know they had this. Thanks!

Comment: No probs. Ray Wenderlich is the best. I'm learning iOS development myself atm. I'm using Stanfords tutorials as well. It's great.